# Select and Delete exactly x rows from MySql table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-delete

I have a MySql table(pin_codes).
At first I want to select exactly 200 rows from this table and export them, then I want to delete this 200 rows.

If the IDs of this table was continuous, I could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM pin_codes WHERE id<200 and id>1;
DELETE FROM pin_codes WHERE id<200 and id>1;
```

But IDs are like this:

```
52138
52139
52141
52142
52144
52147
52148
52157
52158
...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select * from pin_codes order by id limit 200
```

will give you first 200 rows based on id and then you can delete those 200 id's

```
 Delete from pin-codes order by id limit 200
```

to delete first 200 rows

Also it is best practice to use column name instead of * (Query Optimization)

Comment: but how can I determine these IDs? do you mean DELETE 200 times?

Comment: How can I make sure that these 200 rows that was deleted, are those 200 rows that I select previously?

Comment: In That case First You select the 200 rows and then in delete query use where id>=firstid and id<=lastid

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
delete from t1 order by id limit 5;
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cba7/1/0)

Answer (score -1):

MySql:

```
SELECT *  FROM table1
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Sql Server:

```
   Select FROM table1
    WHERE id IN 
    (
      SELECT TOP 200
        id
      FROM table1
      WHERE YourConditions
      ORDER BY ExplicitSortOrder
    )
```

Above query will delete specific subset of rows, you should explicitly specify order to subquery:

To delete the 200 rows use the above query by changing the `Select`  keyword to `Delete`

Comment: @DownVoters may i know what's wrong with my query. it will helpful to identify my mistake

Comment: i guess there will be no TOP n on mysql , that why there may be downvote